# Different baseURL for development and production with Nuxt.js

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

How can I add a different baseURL for development and production?

This is currently my nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
...
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    baseURL: 'http://10.8.0.1:8000',
    credentials: false
  },
...
}
```

For **npm run dev** and **npm run generate** I would like to have different baseURL's.

How can I do this?

## EDIT

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}

console.log(process.env.BASE_URL) // <-- The output is correct (I get the BASE_URL from my env variables

module.exports = {
   ...
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.baseUrl // <-- This is not working, why?
  },
   ...
}
```

Comment: You can use env vars

Comment: Do you have a working example? I do not understand the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

Inside your nuxt.config.js file
add this environment variable

```
   build: { ....},
   env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'localhost'
   }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Where do I set www.devurl.com and where do I set www.productiveurl.com?

Comment: Inside your env file ! on your hosting. Where are you hosting ?

Comment: I'm building a static website with "npm run generate". I want somethink like: if (development) baseURL = www.devurl.com else baseURL =  www.productiveurl.com
Is this possible?

Comment: I updated my post. I am trying to get the BASE_URL from the env. Do you see what I am doing wrong? Do you  have a working project/example on github or somewhere else? Thank you