# How to connect vue.js with Spring Boot rest api on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js

i think i found where the problem exists...I think its on the path of domain on heroku..
This is how my paths on routes looks like and it's pointing to my back end maybe i have to change the path so it must pointing on domain on Heroku and not to Back end

```
routes: [{
      path: "/about",
      component: _ceb3842a,
      name: "about"
    }, {
      path: "/creators",
      component: _c2b5ce4e,
      name: "creators"
    }, {
      path: "/deigmata",
      component: _c8455660,
      name: "deigmata"
    }, {
      path: "/files",
      component: _64a109e6,
      name: "files"
    }, {
      path: "/pictures",
      component: _41f4775b,
      name: "pictures"
    }, {
      path: "/prwtokola",
      component: _8f0c010a,
      name: "prwtokola"
    }, {
      path: "/prwtokola/new",
      component: _10c50cee,
      name: "prwtokola-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh",
      component: _07c7c315,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats",
      component: _8b27d4f0,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn",
      component: _21305152,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh",
      component: _6511de78,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats",
      component: _3091ccf6,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh/new",
      component: _1edb5ba3,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats/new",
      component: _3b47aed6,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh/new",
      component: _1caa1874,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats/new",
      component: _228d8e13,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/map",
      component: _688012dc,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-map"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/new",
      component: _b6c755c0,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-new"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh/dynamic-search/page/:number?",
      component: _7c40b6fc,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh/search/page/:number?",
      component: _132c8c2e,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats/dynamic-search/page/:number",
      component: _173ed629,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats/search/page/:number",
      component: _5c7f285b,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh/dynamic-search/page/:number?",
      component: _91c8218e,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh/search/page/:number?",
      component: _014e516b,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats/dynamic-search/page/:number?",
      component: _2902928c,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats/search/page/:number?",
      component: _7d0af7be,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/dynamic-search/page/:number?",
      component: _6cc5a11f,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/search/page/:number?",
      component: _63396d5e,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/deigmata/dynamic-search/page/:number?",
      component: _74f7ade1,
      name: "deigmata-dynamic-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/deigmata/search/page/:number?",
      component: _a2f18fda,
      name: "deigmata-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/files/search/page/:number?",
      component: _4fed4594,
      name: "files-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/pictures/search/page/:number?",
      component: _28626928,
      name: "pictures-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/prwtokola/search/page/:number?",
      component: _ff5485f0,
      name: "prwtokola-search-page-number"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh/:id?",
      component: _bb6fa1b6,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh-id"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats/:id?",
      component: _b07726dc,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats-id"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh/:id?",
      component: _81f28cbc,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh-id"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats/:id?",
      component: _40c54296,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats-id"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?",
      component: _3bc001f0,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-eidh/:id?/edit",
      component: _6d6208f2,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-eidh-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/ct-press-threats/:id?/edit",
      component: _13cedc7a,
      name: "thhlastika-ct-press-threats-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh/:id?/edit",
      component: _18f2a52c,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-eidh-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats/:id?/edit",
      component: _4864cc12,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-x-press-threats-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?/edit",
      component: _79c7b978,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?/files",
      component: _5c8641b5,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id-files"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?/pictures",
      component: _d4a7609a,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id-pictures"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?/x-eidh",
      component: _310865ea,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id-x-eidh"
    }, {
      path: "/thhlastika/deigma-thhlastikwn/:id?/x-press-threats",
      component: _ce763f5c,
      name: "thhlastika-deigma-thhlastikwn-id-x-press-threats"
    }, {
      path: "/deigmata/:id",
      component: _011f7a4a,
      name: "deigmata-id"
    }, {
      path: "/prwtokola/:id",
      component: _bcac7b02,
      name: "prwtokola-id"
    }, {
      path: "/deigmata/:id/edit",
      component: _507f37c2,
      name: "deigmata-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/prwtokola/:id/edit",
      component: _242094ed,
      name: "prwtokola-id-edit"
    }, {
      path: "/",
      component: _8f43cea0,
      name: "index"
    }],

    fallback: false
  })
}
```

And this is how one of my domains in my back end looks like

```
package com.teicm.kerkinibackend.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Prwtokola {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "prwtokola")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Deigmata> deigmataSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "perigrafh")
    private String perigrafh;

    @Column(name = "pinakas_dedomenwn")
    private String pinakasDedomenwn;

    @Column(name = "parathuro_dedomenwn")
    private String parathuroDedomenwn;

    public void addDeigma(Deigmata deigmata){
        deigmata.setPrwtokola(this);
        this.deigmataSet.add(deigmata);
    }

    public void removeDeigma(Deigmata deigmata){
        deigmata.setPrwtokola(null);
        this.deigmataSet.remove(deigmata);
    }

    public Prwtokola() {
    }

    public Prwtokola(Set<Deigmata> deigmataSet, String perigrafh, String pinakasDedomenwn, String parathuroDedomenwn) {
        this.deigmataSet = deigmataSet;
        this.perigrafh = perigrafh;
        this.pinakasDedomenwn = pinakasDedomenwn;
        this.parathuroDedomenwn = parathuroDedomenwn;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Deigmata> getDeigmataSet() {
        return deigmataSet;
    }

    public void setDeigmataSet(Set<Deigmata> deigmataSet) {
        this.deigmataSet = deigmataSet;
    }

    public String getPerigrafh() {
        return perigrafh;
    }

    public void setPerigrafh(String perigrafh) {
        this.perigrafh = perigrafh;
    }

    public String getPinakasDedomenwn() {
        return pinakasDedomenwn;
    }

    public void setPinakasDedomenwn(String pinakasDedomenwn) {
        this.pinakasDedomenwn = pinakasDedomenwn;
    }

    public String getParathuroDedomenwn() {
        return parathuroDedomenwn;
    }

    public void setParathuroDedomenwn(String parathuroDedomenwn) {
        this.parathuroDedomenwn = parathuroDedomenwn;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to connect your Vue.js application running on Heroku to a back-end Spring Boot application running on your local machine? Why? Normally you'd run the back-end on the internet as well. (Heroku would work fine.)

Comment: I saw your update before it was deleted as a non-answer. Specifically, what does "can't access my database and can't register new values" mean? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? Please read [ask].

Comment: cant access my database i mean i  i cant navigate the paths of domains on heroku..sorry my english isnt that good i am having hard time right now to trying to explain you..:P.this is the site i am working on..if this helps https://kerkini2.herokuapp.com/ At the left side of the site all these are tables..and there are options for giving a new record and search for them..so my problem is other pc's cant create a new record and search records..its just doesnt work..i have no errors at all

Comment: Are there error messages in your browser's developer tools or your server-side runtime logs (see `heroku logs`)?

Comment: No i dont get any errors while i am running it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ncxqxq This the button i apply for making a new record in the database and its not working and this is the view log on heroku http://prntscr.com/ncxrko

Comment: i think i found where the problem exists...In this picture http://prntscr.com/nd3cbs How can find the path of domain on heroku and there http://prntscr.com/nd3dkx is the back end

Comment: Thanks for adding information. Generally speaking, please share text as _text_, not screenshots. Screenshots can't be indexed for search, the text they show can't be copied, and they're difficult to consume with adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, you can [edit] your question and paste code directly into it, then select the code and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54516511/354577